# I want to have a "Sign Up with Facebook" feature for my php application

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, registration

We are creating a PHP MySQL application in which we have a registration form for the users.

We want "Sign Up with Facebook" functionality as well for the registration.

I have googled about it but I could only find the code for the Login functionality for Facebook. If anyone could help me to find the exact resource to know about the Registration through Facebook feature, it would be really great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The duplicate this was closed with did not seem appropriate to me, so I re-opened the question. BUT, asking us to help find external resources such as tutorials etc., would be considered off-topic here to begin with - so if you need any of those, you need to go and search or ask for them elsewhere.

Comment: Apart from that - “registration via Facebook” is something you have to implement yourself. Facebook provides only the login functionality. You can request user details such as their app-scoped user id, name and e-mail then, to use as basic data for your own site’s registration system. (Careful, you won’t be able to _get_ an e-mail address from every Facebook user, so if your system needs one, you have to implement an additional step to ask the user for one in these cases. Confirming that e-mail address as real is also your responsibility then in that situation.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To piggyback on CBroe's answer, Facebook only has login however, you can use the continue with button as a psuedo "registration" button. Here's where to find/configure the continue with button: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/login-button/
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web

With the results from Facebook based on their docs, get the variables you need to register a user in your system. Here's what I am doing to combat the same issue. I have a function called getUserInfo() below:

```
function getUserInfo() {

    // Get what you need from FB's graphQL API
    FB.api('/me?fields=id,email,first_name,last_name', function (response, global) {

        // Set variables based on results of '/me' Graphql call
        let fbuserid = response.id;
        let fbuserfname = response.first_name;
        let fbuserlname = response.last_name;
        let fbuseremail = response.email;

        // I am defining variables for my site's registration form fields
        let fname = document.getElementById('fname');
        let lname = document.getElementById('lname');
        let email = document.getElementById('email');

        // Set input values in your form from the facebook results
        fname.value = fbuserfname;
        lname.value = fbuserlname;
        email.value = fbuseremail;

        // I make up a password but you don't have to
        var md = forge.md.sha256.create();
        md.update(fbuserid + fbuseremail + randomString());
        document.getElementById('pwrd').value = md.digest().toHex();

        // My form has steps so I auto-progress users to the next step since the Javascript filled in the form already. Completely optional
        document.getElementById("nextbutton").click();

    });
}
```

I call the getUserInfo() function in the FB button after the login event like this:

```
<div id="fbregister" data-size="medium" data-button-type="continue_with" data-layout="default" data-auto-logout-link="false" data-use-continue-as="false" data-scope="email" data-onlogin="getUserInfo()"></div>
```

What happens overall is, users click, continue with facebook, they login, the function is called, fields are set via JS and users progress to the next step. Once they finish the next steps, they are registered. I hope this helps got you off to the right start.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will try this out and let you know if i were able to set it up. Thanks.

Comment: Your code did help me a lot to get the email address of the facebook user. In the same way, can I get the password of the user? I have searched on this. But I didnt get any idea on how to get the password of the facebook user.

Comment: Basically what I want is, I have a "Login with Facebook" button. When the user clicks on the button, I have to get their email address as well as password and check in the database of my system. If the user already exists, then I have to allow them to login.

Comment: Facebook doesn't share the user's password which is why I am using a JS cryptography library to create a password for the user. 
Facebook permissions reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions
JS Library for various cryptography:https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge

You can ask the user to create their own password on first login later.